# Clip-path not honouring axis in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a clippath which works on most of my elements, except a custom axis that I am rendering. In the example https://jsfiddle.net/7992sgbe/ you can see that when you move/pan the lines. The blue axes does not honour the clipath. I attempted repositioning the order of the clip in the code, but that does not seem to have any effect.

```
var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

The code for the axes is as below

```
var make_x_marker = function (scale=1, transform=[0,0]) {

    console.log(transform)
    var markers =[];
    var markerLabels={};
    for (i=0; i<raw['ecg-markers'].length; i++)
    {

    var value=(1000/244.140625)*raw['ecg-markers'][i];
    value=x(raw.meta.startts+value) 
     markers.push(value)
     markerLabels[value]="A"+Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
    }

    return d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("top")
        .tickValues(markers)
        .tickSize(height-15)
        .tickFormat(function(d){return markerLabels[d]})


};

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x marker")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_marker());
```

Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're placing the blue lines in the wrong container, so the clip path doesn't know about them. Append to chart body instead of SVG.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/7992sgbe/1/

```
var chartBody = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

chartBody.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x marker")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(make_x_marker());
```

PS

I have edited your code as you have a lot of duplicate code which can be written with less code using for loops. Example :

This

```
svg.select(".line0")
    .attr("class", "line0")
    .attr("d", line0);

  svg.select(".line1")
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .attr("d", line1);

  svg.select(".line2")
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("d", line2);

  svg.select(".line3")
    .attr("class", "line3")
    .attr("d", line3);

  svg.select(".line4")
    .attr("class", "line4")
    .attr("d", line4);

  svg.select(".line5")
    .attr("class", "line5")
    .attr("d", line5);
```

Can be written like this :

```
var linesArray = [line0, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5]

for (var i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
  chartBody.append("svg:path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line" + i)
    .attr("d", linesArray[i]);
}
```

I have also edited the one in the zoom function